# How to Add Foreign Key with Extra Information in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have 2 tables departments and locations and locationID is the primary key in locations table and departments table also has that field.

Now after adding a data with locationID 101 in the departments table it won't let me add foreign key referencing locations table because the locations table doesn't have any data with locationID 101 so the data with locationID 101 is extra in the departments table that doesn't belong in locations table.

So how do I fix that without deleting the information from departments table or adding the info in locations table (if possible)?

Comment: Why you are trying to create a constraint which your data is planned to violate?

Comment: I wanted to know if there's a way to declare the foreign key even after having the extra data

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. "fix" what? What exactly is your question? PS Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [foreign key constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) and the behavior is as expected.

If you don't want it at all, you can make the two tables independent of each other, i.e. don't make `locationID` a foreign key in `department` table, rather let it be a different `locationID` having no relation to the locations table.

Otherwise, you can temporarily disable the foreign key constraint by following [Disabling foreign key constraint](https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/08/mysql-how-to-temporarily-disable-foreign-key-constraints.html). But this can lead to a lot of problem in maintaining the tables, in future.

Comment: But I wanted to know if there's a way to declare the foreign key even after having the extra data like any way to bypass the existing data that doesn't corelate

Comment: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;  Is this not working for you, it's from the second link I have shared in answer, remember to make it one, once done.